# Drive audio card manually in C

Tags: audio, pci-e

I'm embedded programmer and using C. I wan to know how I can access audio board low level access. I know audio cards are connected to PCIe, then I must using the registers of south bridge to connecting to audio card, is it possible? what is the starting point?

I know there is some libraries like WASAPI for windows. But as embedded man I want to access audio buffer directly through PCIe.

Comment: Take a look at open source device drivers for Linux perhaps.

Comment: For example: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.11/sound/kernel-api/writing-an-alsa-driver.html.   If you are doing this in Windows, you will still need to write a device driver to get the privileged access required.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to have very in-depth knowledge about how your specific card works. The way that I see it you have two options:

- You write a driver so you can get a really low level, but still accessible on the OS side interface
- You make a break-out board for your card and interface with the card that way

My question is, why do you want to do this? If you want to experiment with digital to analog signal generation, busting out a cheap microcontroller (such as an arduino), an audio amplifier, and a small speaker would be a great way to get started.

Comment: Microcontrollers are really great. But they are not like PC have high computing capability. If I could change my platform to PC, many problems will be solved. 1.High processing power provided by PC is extremely nice 2.cahllenging with MCU complex structure for handling and synchronizing data will be vanishes. 3.We have high quality audio front-end in PC audio cards. PC's are everywhere I will never encounter PC shortage.

Comment: So, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48755106/passing-data-to-from-a-pcie-device) sort of confirms my suspicions. You're going to need a driver that exposes the card to the user space. This is much more easily done on Linux. Sorry that I can't provide more help than this.